# Intel Cluster Studio cannot detect a glibc library on the system

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I'm trying to install Intel Parallel Studio XE 2016 on Arch Linux but the installation script complains that an Optional Prerequisite is missing:

> The install program cannot detect a glibc library on the system. The product requires a glibc library version 2.3.4 or higher. Contact your system
>   administrator to install a compliant version of glibc or install product on a
>   compliant system.

I have glibc version 2.22 installed. How can I inform the script that glibc is in fact present at the standard location? If I skip the warning and proceed with the installation, I get

```
 Step 5 of 6 | Installation
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Each component will be installed individually. If you cancel the installation,
 some components might remain on your system. This installation may take several 
 minutes, depending on your system and the options you selected.
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Installing Intel(R) MPI Library, Runtime Environment for applications running on
 Intel(R) 64 Architecture component...Uninstalling Intel(R) MPI Benchmarks component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) MPI Library, Runtime Environment for applications running 
 on Intel(R) 64 Architecture component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) MPI Library, Runtime Environment for applications running 
 on Intel(R) Many Integrated Core Architecture component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) MPI Library for applications running on Intel(R) 64
 Architecture component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) MPI Library for applications running on Intel(R) Many
 Integrated Core Architecture component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) Trace Analyzer for Intel(R) 64 Architecture component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) Trace Collector for Intel(R) 64 Architecture component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) Trace Collector for Intel(R) Many Integrated Core
 Architecture component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Cluster Checker common files component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Cluster Checker Analyzer component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Cluster Checker Collector component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Cluster Checker Database component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Command line interface component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Sampling Driver kit component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Graphical user interface component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Command line interface component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Graphical user interface component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Command line interface component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Graphical user interface component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel C++ Compiler for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel C++ Compiler for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel Fortran Compiler for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel Fortran Compiler for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel MKL core libraries for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) coprocessor support component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Fortran 95 interfaces for BLAS and LAPACK for Intel(R) 64
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling GNU* Compiler Collection support for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling PGI* compiler support for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling SP2DP interface for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Cluster support for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel MKL core libraries for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Fortran 95 interfaces for BLAS and LAPACK for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling GNU* Compiler Collection support for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling PGI* compiler support for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel TBB threading support for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel TBB threading support for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP single-threaded libraries for IA-32: General package
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP single-threaded libraries for Intel(R) 64: General
 package component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP multi-threaded libraries for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP multi-threaded libraries for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP Cryptography single-threaded for IA-32 for Linux
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP Cryptography single-threaded for Intel(R) 64 for Linux
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel Cryptography IPP multi-threaded for Intel(R) 64 for Linux
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel Cryptography IPP multi-threaded for IA-32 for Linux
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP Cryptography single-threaded for Intel(R) 64 for Android 
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel IPP Cryptography single-threaded for IA-32 for Android
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel TBB source code component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel TBB component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel DAAL for IA-32 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Intel DAAL for Intel(R) 64 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling GNU* GDB 7.6 (Provided under GNU General Public License v3)
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Source of GNU* GDB 7.6 (Provided under GNU General Public License
 v3) component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling libelfdwarf.so library and it's sources (Provided under GNU Lesser 
 General Public License) component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling GDB Eclipse* Integration on Intel(R) 64 (Provided under Eclipse
 Public License v.1.0) component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Source of GDB Eclipse* Integration (Provided under Eclipse Public
 License v.1.0) component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling GNU* GDB 7.8 on Intel(R) 64 (Provided under GNU General Public
 License v3) component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Source of GNU* GDB 7.8 (Provided under GNU General Public License
 v3) component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Uninstalling Python sources (Provided under Python Software Foundation License) 
 component...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalizing product configuration...
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.0.047/documentation_2016’: No such file or directory
 ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.0.047/samples_2016’: No such file or directory
 chmod: cannot access ‘/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.0.047/uninstall’: No such file or directory
 Press "Enter" key to continue
```

I don't understand why it's trying to uninstall things, because I have not used Intel products on this computer before. Any suggestions are welcome.